# BigQuery array intersect

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an array of values I'd like to filter results for if an array column contains any of these values, is there an easy way to perform an intersect in BigQuery using the standard SQL language?

Answer (score 6):

This should give you the general direction:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(array_column) a WHERE a IN UNNEST(array_values))
```